# Generate square from center point?

Tags: java, shapes

I have coordinates of the center point of a square I would like to generate, the only bits of information I have is the location of the center point (example: 4,9) and the width/height (example: 10) of the square. I want to loop over every pixel of the square.

Each block here represents a loop, the gold is the location of the "center" (I know it's off-center because it's an even number). https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7sb1.jpg

The width will always be the same as the height and vice versa, however they can be any number from 1-25.

Comment: You can probably use the java.lang.Math class to do the math.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a loop in a loop

```
int midX = 4; //set this
int midY = 9; //set this
int size = 13; //set this

int _upperLeftX = midX - size/2;
int _upperLeftY = midY - size/2;
for(int y = _upperLeftY; y < size + _upperLeftY; y++) {
    for(int x = _upperLeftX; x < size + _upperLeftX; x++) {
        //Put your code to create a block here. Take x,y as coordinates
    }
}
```